# How to find the points in the image?

Tags: opencv

See the below image: How to find all the points by OpenCV? I use the `traincascade`,  but it's not effective.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) on your own, and (2) learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here. Please provide a [mre] to your _specific_ problem. What have you tried so far? Please show any relevant code. Also, please specify a programming language by adding a proper tag. Finally, please provide a clean input image, i.e. without the red squares (if possible).

Comment: Inverse binarize the input image. Apply morphological opening using a proper sized circular kernel. Most likely, the larger arrowheads will also survive. Find all contours, check for "roundness" (arrowheads will be more elliptical, and sort out all contours, which are not "round" enough.

Comment: Template matching could be also an option if all the "points" are having the same size.

Comment: Could you add the original input image?